# Jquery Datatables

Tags: jquery-datatables

Tenho um array com números de concursos de loteria e joguei em uma datatable.
Gostaria de saber se é possível digitar no filtro o número do concurso que eu quero e ele ao invés de filtrar apenas aquele número, apenas me trouxesse os dados do item e os botões anterior e próximo apontassem respectivamente para os próximos. Exemplo este site da caixa. http://loterias.caixa.gov.br/wps/portal/loterias/landing/lotofacil/

Estou utilizando o DataTables 1.10.7.

index.html

```
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="dataTable1" class="table table-bordered table-striped-col" data-info="false">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Resultados Lotofácil</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>
              <script type="text/javascript">

             var LFcontador = localStorage.getItem("LFcontador");
             if(LFcontador == 0)
             {
                document.write('<br>Não há resultados carregados no momento.');
             }
             else
             {
                 for(j=LFcontador-1;j>=0;j--)  
                 {                             
                     document.write('<tr><td><strong>Concurso: </strong>'+localStorage.getItem("LFConcurso-"+j)+'<br><strong>Números: </strong>'+localStorage.getItem("LFBol1-"+j)+'-'+localStorage.getItem("LFBol2-"+j)+'-'+localStorage.getItem("LFBol3-"+j)+'-'+localStorage.getItem("LFBol4-"+j)+'-'+localStorage.getItem("LFBol5-"+j)+'-'+localStorage.getItem("LFBol6-"+j)+'-'+localStorage.getItem("LFBol7-"+j)+'-'+localStorage.getItem("LFBol8-"+j)+'-'+localStorage.getItem("LFBol9-"+j)+'-'+localStorage.getItem("LFBol10-"+j)+'-'+localStorage.getItem("LFBol11-"+j)+'-'+localStorage.getItem("LFBol12-"+j)+'-'+localStorage.getItem("LFBol13-"+j)+'-'+localStorage.getItem("LFBol14-"+j)+'-'+localStorage.getItem("LFBol15-"+j)+'</td></tr>');                             
                 }
             }
         </script>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
```

Comment: Adicione o código atual da sua datatable

Comment: Não consigo adicionar o código, ultrapassa o limite de caracteres aqui, Tem alguma forma de anexar os arquivos?

Comment: Tadeu, posta aqui somente a parte relevante, referente ao seu datatable. O resto você pode linkar no pastebin, por exemplo, para servir de referencia.

Comment: Alguma ajuda pessoal?

Comment: Eu só quero implementar esse tipo de paginação de 1 item por página junto com a opção de busca do item. Da maneira que funciona o site que postei da caixa, porém, sem usar php.